# Cannot write file pri: Cannot create parent directory in QT mac os

Tags: c++, mysql, macos, qt

I am trying to build mysql driver in QT Creator in osx, but I get

> error: Cannot write file
>   /mkspecs/modules-inst/qt_plugin_qsqlmysql.pri: Cannot create parent
>   directory

Thats the pro file

```
TARGET = qsqlmysql

HEADERS += $$PWD/qsql_mysql_p.h
SOURCES += $$PWD/qsql_mysql.cpp $$PWD/main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += /usr/local/mysql-5.7.12-osx10.11-x86_64/include
QMAKE_LIBDIR += /usr/local/mysql-5.7.12-osx10.11-x86_64/lib/
LIBS += -lmysql
QMAKE_USE += mysql

OTHER_FILES += mysql.json

PLUGIN_CLASS_NAME = QMYSQLDriverPlugin
include(../qsqldriverbase.pri)
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to install a Qt plugin, so you need write permissions to Qt's installation directory.

You'll have to build Qt yourself and keep it in the home directory you've got write access to.

Perhaps it'd be better to use Qt from MacPorts, then you'd simply need to `sudo port install qt5-mysql-plugin`.

Comment: I have this issue too, I'd like some clarification about whether qt uses its own user or what. I installed into `/usr/local/Qt-[ver]` and made sure I have recursive ownership of the whole folder, but it's not enough. *EDIT* Even doing a `chmod -R 777` on the directory fails to allow me to write, so I'm thinking it may be more complicated.

Comment: After playing with permissions, I did `chmod -R 775` and restarted QTCreator and didn't get the error anymore.